# PHP - Is there a better way find an integer out of a few?

Tags: php, integer

Currently I'm using the following approach to determine if `$userlevel` is either `10`, `20`, or `30`.

```
if ( in_array( $userlevel, array( 10, 20, 30 ) ) ) { 

}
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I just didn't know if this was a standard way to find an integer within a group of integers or not. I just used in_array because it made sense and was quick. I already tried using strpos() but that doesn't really work for me.

Comment: I'd suggest pulling the array out, just in case you decide to use it again elsewhere. Other than that, this is a pretty common approach to avoiding winded conditions in if-statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are already using the "better way". The alternative would be

```
if ($userlevel == 10 || $userlevel == 20 || $userlevel == 30) {

}
```

Typically you'd write a basic `if` statement until the number of possible values grows such that the line becomes too long, and then you move them into a collection and use `in_array`.

If you know that `$userlevel` will *always* be one of those values, you could simply test that it's between the upper/lower bound, but this won't be any shorter than the way you're writing it now.

Answer (score 3):

I think there is not a "better" way. It depends on what you expect the values you want to choose from develop in the future. You could use a switch with no break.

```
switch ($userlevel) {
    case 10: case 20: case 30
        // ..
        break;
    default:
        // ..
}
```

### Edit

Of course there is 
 great benefit from the `in_array` solution. You can store your **decision** array in a variable and  are able to influence it from somewhere else.

Comment: Clever. While I generally prefer `in_array`, I'll give you an upvote for creativity ;)

Answer (score 0):

There are no better way comparison with in_array.